# Mongoose: Is there a way to default lean to true (always on)?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a read-only API that I'd like Mongoose to always have [lean queries](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) for.

Can I enable this either on a schema or connection level to be true by default?

Comment: Doesn't seem that you can apply it at schema level (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#options), so I doubt that you can do it on connection level either :/

Comment: You might consider just using the mongodb native driver directly -- it's always *lean*.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - need mongoose on this project for other reasons, but thanks.

Comment: you can use them in the same project. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way is to monkey patch `mongoose.Query` class to add default lean option:

```
var __setOptions = mongoose.Query.prototype.setOptions;

mongoose.Query.prototype.setOptions = function(options, overwrite) {
  __setOptions.apply(this, arguments);
  if (this.options.lean == null) this.options.lean = true;
  return this;
};
```

Mongoose creates new instance of `mongoose.Query` for every query and `setOptions` call is a part of `mongoose.Query` construction.

By patching `mongoose.Query` class you'll be able to turn lean queries on globally. So you won't need to path all `mongoose` methods (`find`, `findOne`, `findById`, `findOneAndUpdate`, etc.).

`Mongoose` uses `Query` class for inner calls like populate. It passes original `Query` options to each sub-query, so there *should be* no problems, but be careful with this solution anyway.

Comment: Much better answer than mine, kudos to you!

Comment: this does not work with node 6.7.0 and mongoose 4.5.8. Any idea why?

Comment: In mongoose 4.5.8 I had to change "this.options.lean" to "this.mongooseOptions.lean".

Comment: Using mongoose 5.4.9, it worked by doing: ```if (this.mongooseOptions().lean == null) { this.mongooseOptions({ lean: true }); }```

Comment: How would this work in TS? The query return type will still be `Document`, so the whole typing will be useless. Is there a way to declare that all query returns `LeanDocument`?

Answer (score 2):

A hack-around could be performed something like this:

Current way of executing the query:

```
Model.find().lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
    docs[0] instanceof mongoose.Document // false
});
```

Fiddle with the `Model`'s `find` method:

```
var findOriginal = Model.prototype.find;
Model.prototype.find = function() {
    return findOriginal.apply(this, arguments).lean();
}
```

New way of executing the query:

```
Model.find().exec(function (err, docs) {
    docs[0] instanceof mongoose.Document // false
});
```

I have **not tested** this code, but if you have tried to override library functionality in JavaScript before, you will easily grasp where I'm getting

Comment: You will of course have to perform this hack for every Model definition, unless you want to dig deeper into the source code of Mongoose :)

Answer (score 1):

I have to use My nestjs Application like this. Its perfectly working for me.

```
import { Query } from 'mongoose'

Query.prototype.setOptions = function(options: any) {
  __setOptions.apply(this, arguments)
  if (!this.mongooseOptions().lean) this.mongooseOptions().lean = true
  return this
}
```

Comment: I want to point out that there is a critical issue with this code sample.  If a user explicitly sets the lean option to false, it will set it to true.  This is why it is important to do:
if (!this.mongooseOptions().lean == null)
as this will only fall through if the provided lean option is null or undefined.

Comment: @Krrish Which file did you put these codes

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the above comments:

```js
mongoose.Query.prototype.setOptions = function(options, overwrite) {
    options = Object.assign({}, options);
    if (!options.hasOwnProperty('lean')) {
        options.lean = true;
    }
    __setOptions.call(this, options, overwrite);
    return this;
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the accepted answer by @Leonid Beschastny, the places where you **should not use lean**, according to Mongoose docs are:

- When you modify the query result
- You use custom getters or transforms

Source: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html#when-to-use-lean

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add the default lean option for a mongoose model.
Just add these three lines.

**For Example:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const BreakTimeTrackerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {
        type: Number
    },
    company_id: {
        type: Number
    },
    break_time: {
        type: Number
    }
}, {timestamps: true});

BreakTimeTrackerSchema.set('lean', true);
BreakTimeTrackerSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true });
BreakTimeTrackerSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });
module.exports = mongoose.model("break_time_tracker", BreakTimeTrackerSchema);
```