# Overriding mongoose query for a specific model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to automatically  add a query option for all queries related for a specific mongoose model without affecting other models

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19186230/553460) where Mongoose.Query is patched and that will affect all mongoose models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two possible easy ways to do this:

**Alternative #1**

Add a static dict with the options you want to be applied to your specific Mongoose schema:

```
FooSchema.statics.options = {
    ...
};
```

Now, when you query you need to do:

```
Foo.find({}, null, Foo.options, function(err, foos) {
    ...
});
```

**Alternative #2**

Implement a wrapper to the find method that always uses your specific options:

```
FooSchema.statics.findWithOptions = function(query, next) {
    var options = { ... };
    this.find(query, null, options, next);
};
```

And use this method like so:

```
Foo.findWithOptions({}, function(err, foos) {
    ...
})
```

**Reusability**

To make these wrapper methods more reusable, you can make a dict with all your wrappers:

```
var withOptionsWrappers = {
    findWithOptions: function(query, next) {
        this.find(query, null, this.options, next);
    },
    findByIdWithOptions: ...
    findOneWithOptions: ...
    ...
};
```

Since we're referring to `this` there will be no problem reusing this. And now have this be applied to all your schemas along with your schema specific options:

```
FooSchema.statics = withOptionsWrappers;
FooSchema.statics.options = {
    ...
};
BarSchema.statics = withOptionsWrappers;
BarSchema.statics.options = {
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but actually i want to add this option to all queries (find,findById,update,remove...) so i need to create wrapper for each query for each model !

Comment: @eyadof added a section in my answer that gives a suggestion how you can reuse it.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to do this for my soft deleted items. Haven't tested it extensively yet though.

```
function findNotDeletedMiddleware(next) {
    this.where('deleted').equals(false);
    next();
}

MySchema.pre('find', findNotDeletedMiddleware);
MySchema.pre('findOne', findNotDeletedMiddleware);
MySchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', findNotDeletedMiddleware);
MySchema.pre('count', findNotDeletedMiddleware);
```