# Apply lean({virtuals: true}.exec() to all applicable mongoose calls by default

Tags: mongoose

Is there is a sane way to patch mongoose to treat all calls like `Model.findById()` and `Model.find()` as `Model.findById().lean({virtuals: true}).exec()` and `Model.find().lean({virtuals: true}).exec()`.

I found an example of [monkey patching to apply lean by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183886/mongoose-is-there-a-way-to-default-lean-to-true-always-on/19184142), but it doesn't solve the problem above.